# Is it optimal to create multiple db connection in .NET API project or create linked server (all are SQL Servers)and access the db objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a .NET API project where am accessing multiple database from multiple SQL Servers.

I am using Entity Framework Core db first approach.
Is it optimal to used linked server and have a single `dbcontext`, will there be any performance issue or security concern. Or its better to use multiple dbcontext?

Comment: This link may prove useful. Check and see if "connection pool fragmentation" applies to your use case. This would mainly pertain to a multi-tenant situation where you need to connect to say 100 databases -->  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Answer (score 2):

Definitely optimal to use separate connections for each database.  You’ll get a separate connection pool for each one.